# react - onselect change display previous value

Tags: reactjs, redux, onselect

I'm fairly new to React.

I have selector which returns whatever the user selects.

#### Code Example:

```js
handleChanged(e){
    const { onSelectcountry } = this.props;
    onSelectcountry(e.target.value)
}
return (
    <div>       
        <Input type="select" name="select" value={Country} onChange={this.handleChanged.bind(this)}>
        { 
            country.map((item) => {
              return (<option value={item._id} key={item._id}> {item.name}</option>);
            })
        }
        </Input>
    </div>
);
```

i dispatch action depend on user select,

```
import { fetchNews} from '../../actions';

    getNews(filterNews) {
        const { fetchNews } = this.props;
        fetchNews(filterNews);
    }
    onSelectcountry(country) {
        this.setState({ Country: country});
        this.getNews({
          this.state,
        })
    }

    <CountrySelector  onSelectcountry={this.onSelectcountry.bind(this)}   Country={Country}/>
```

The problem is: When the selected value changes, it shows the value of the previous selection.

Comment: It's probably a setState synchronicity issue - Could you post the code via CodeSandbox?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the asynchronous nature of `setState`
You have some options:

1. use setState's optional callback, it will be invoked after updating state.

```js
    onSelectcountry(country) {
        this.setState(
          { Country: country},
          () => this.getNews({ this.state })
        );
    }
```

2. Call `getNews` with manually composed arguments

```
    onSelectcountry(country) {
        this.setState({ Country: country });
        this.getNews({
          ...this.state,
          Country: country
        })
    }
```

3. Call `getNews` in [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) callback, e.g. leave onSelectcountry simple and care only about Country state updates, and handle real state update in expected manner.

```js
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
      // coundition may vary depending on your requirements
      if (this.state.Country !== prevState.Country) {
        this.getNews(this.state);
      }
    }

    onSelectcountry(country) {
        this.setState({ Country: country});
    }
```

Comment: it work fine, thanks so much, I appreciate your support in every way